# PHP sendmail form is sending blank e-mail, how can I fix java script?

Tags: javascript, php, sendmail

I had problem all day about sendmail.php. First I had proble to not receive e-mail I fix it than I start to receive e-mail blank. I undestand the problem wasn't php code or html code, problem was java script wich is attached to contact-form.

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

this is the code which is sending blank e-mail. I read an answer similar problem and I understand that I should use this;

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
```

When I changed recommended code to my code I start to receive e-mail with name topic and message but after clicking the "Send Now" botton page turn to white blank instead of giving message as "Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you"

So I think I couldn't combine to correct code to mine. Can anybody help me to add `$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {` to my scrpt?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: No Jay, I just pay money to buy this theme with very normal expectation that it will work. But I found many mistakes on coding. I have no idea what is AJAX or any other questions just I can say that it works as I am using second code (works mean receive e-mail) but page turn to white after click send now button.

Comment: You bought this and want us to fix it for you? That will be impossible without knowing the errors.

Comment: Jay it is fixed you can see answer down side.

Comment: Jay Jay I am not in the mood of discuss but I can tell you one. Aim to "earn point" or "accepting answers" is not helping to solve my problem otherwise I receive more questions to my questions as you did. What it helps to me without concern of "earn points" or show how you have deep knowledge simply answer of question. Tiberiu Petcu did. I am really appriciate to him. I think you must talk to him not to answer questions but "earn points" )) Have a nice day Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use your code but with two changes, add a "method" to your ajax request, and some data to send to the server. Also make sure you're working with POST values in the php file

```
    var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```